# Capitalization of Appendix in Table of Contents and in Text

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I would like the name to be "APPENDIX A: SUPPLEMENTARY INFORMATION".

I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
   \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

   \begin{document}

   \renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
   \appendix
   \chapter{SUPPLEMENTARY INFORMATION}

   \end{document}
```

The result is the Appendix name being uppercase in the text as "APPENDIX A: SUPPLEMENTARY INFORMATION" but in the table of contents it overlaps as shown in the attached image.

How would I fix this issue?

[image: Overlapping of Appendix in Table of Contents]

Comment: @Allen_Rahrooh Can you please supply us with compilable code that generates the output pictured. The code you currently provide in not compilable without some assumptions and those assumptions may lead to output different from yours.

Comment: @OliverFishCode the output requires  a .cls file that is used as a template so that is why i cant provide it since it would be too long. Upon looking in the code i figured out the issue and added a space after \appendix to the template code and it fixed the issue